# Обработка массива прогнозов PHP,SQL(MySQL)

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Работаю над проектом "Прогноз продажи продукции".
Каждый зарегистрированый пользователь является seller(ом), у которого свой список customer(ов).
Прогноз совершается на каждую неделю отдельно по списку customer(ов) данного seller(а), сроком на 4 месяца, по каждому customer(у) для всех продуктов. Собственно с сортировкой по по неделям все хорошо.
Как лучше и эффективнее обработать сортировку к примеру за месяц. Так как при SQL SELECT мы получаем данные каждого customer(а) по каждому товару за 4 недели, после чего нужно сложить поля (кол-во товара и общая стоимость) где seller_id, customer_id, product_id одинаковые и получить данные о customer(ах) уже за целый месяц, где напротив каждого товара будет указан суммарный прогноз за 4 недели и суммарное количество товара. Спасибо за Ваше время.

Comment: Приведите вопрос к читаемому виду. Читать эту мешанину сложно.

Comment: Так уже получше, мне скорее всего нужен алгоритм в направлении реализации. Я планирую получить массив данных с бд в PHP, после необходимо обойти массив, найти прогнозы у которых одинаковые product_id, customer_id, seller_id и сложить их колонки количества товара и прогнозируемая сумма. И после создать новый массив в который все это дело можно будет запушить

Comment: Лучше, но воспринимать ещё сложно. Отступы, абзацы, списки, выделения и пр. не просто так сделали.

Comment: Приношу извинения за плохую читаемость, теперь лучше